# Shopping Cart Rule : add a 10% dicsount if a SKU is added at least 3 times to the shopping cart

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I need to create a condition which applies a 10% discount on a particular sku, when it has a quantity equal or greater than 3.

How can I achieve this in the Magento admin cart rules section ?

Answer (score 0):

To add specific condition on a special item, you should use the conditions under the "Actions" dropdown.

- For the rule action, select "Percent of product price discount"
- For the discount amount, enter "10" for a 10% discount
- In the conditions applied to the cart items, do the following :

  - If **ALL** of there conditions are **TRUE**

    - SKU **is** **12345** *(enter your SKU here instead)*
    - Quantity in cart **equals or greater than** **3**

You should end up with a something like this :
[image]

Comment: but purchase with other product multiple cart rule apply, i want to apply one cart only this sku

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. This condition will only be applied on the specific SKU. Do you need to have a 10% on the **whole cart** when you have at least the `12345` product 3 times ?
Or do you need to be able to add multiple cart rules to the same cart ?